# Elasticsearch aggregation turns results to lowercase

Tags: elasticsearch, lowercase, analyzer, elasticsearch-aggregation

I've been playing with ElasticSearch a little and found an issue when doing aggregations.

I have two endpoints, **/A** and **/B**. In the first one I have parents for the second one. So, one or many objects in B must belong to one object in A. Therefore, objects in B have an attribute "parentId" with parent index generated by ElasticSearch.

I want to filter parents in A by children attributes of B. In order to do it, I first filter children in B by attributes and get its unique parent ids that I'll later use to get parents.

I send this request:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test/B/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "name",
            "query": "derp2*"
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "ids": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "parentId"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And get this response:

```
{
  "took": 91,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "child",
        "_id": "AU_fjH5u40Hx1Kh6rfQG",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "parentId": "AU_ffvwM40Hx1Kh6rfQA",
          "name": "derp2child2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "child",
        "_id": "AU_fjD_U40Hx1Kh6rfQF",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "parentId": "AU_ffvwM40Hx1Kh6rfQA",
          "name": "derp2child1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "child",
        "_id": "AU_fjKqf40Hx1Kh6rfQH",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "parentId": "AU_ffvwM40Hx1Kh6rfQA",
          "name": "derp2child3"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "ids": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "au_ffvwm40hx1kh6rfqa",
          "doc_count": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, the filtered key is returned in lowercase, hence not being able to request parent to ElasticSearch

```
GET http://localhost:9200/test/A/au_ffvwm40hx1kh6rfqa

Response:
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "A",
  "_id": "au_ffvwm40hx1kh6rfqa",
  "found": false
}
```

Any ideas on why is this happening?

Comment: Your `parentId` needs to be analyzed with `keyword` analyzer or it should be `"index": "not_analyzed"`.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between the hits and the results of the aggregations is that the aggregations work on the created terms. They will also return the terms. The hits return the original source.

How are these terms created? Based on the chosen analyser, which in your case is the default one, the standard analyser. One of the things this analyser does is lowercasing all the characters of the terms. Like mentioned by Andrei, you should configure the field parentId to be not_analyzed.

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "B": {
      "properties": {
        "parentId": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Okay, I see. Will try to update field mappings, guess it will be enough! Thanks!

Comment: I have this same problem with a keyword mapping.. Any ideas why it is happening ?

Answer (score 4):

I am late from the party but I had the same issue and understood that it caused by the normalization.

You have to change the `mapping` of the `index` if you want to prevent any normalization changes the aggregated values to lowercase.

You can check the current mapping in the `DevTools console` by typing

```
GET /A/_mapping
GET /B/_mapping
```

When you see the structure of the index you have to see the setting of the `parentId` field.

If you don't want to change the behaviour of the field but you also want to avoid the normalization during the aggregation then you can add a sub-field to the `parentId` field.

For changing the mapping you have to delete the index and recreate it with the new mapping:

- [creating the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html)
- [Adding multi-fields to an existing field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex)

In your case it looks like this (it contains only the parentId field)

```
PUT /B/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "parentId": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then you have to use the subfield in the query:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test/B/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "name",
      "query": "derp2*"
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "parentId.keyword",
        "order": {"_key": "desc"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The idea of sub-field is correct. Too bad we can't have it some way more intuitive (like some field to retrieve the original value of the source), due to the way ES works.