# Elasticsearch: case insensitive in output of terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I store the a field of value like 'AA', but when using terms aggregation in search, it returns the value in lowercase like 'aa'.

when search with aggs like this:

```
POST /113/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Jack"
    }
  }, 
    "aggs" : {
      "gender" : {
        "terms" : {
        "field" : "gender"
        }
      },
      "grade" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "grade",
            "order" : {"_count" : "asc"}
        }

      }
    }
}
```

outputs like this:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1.3862944,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "113",
        "_type": "default_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.07419574,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Tome Jack",
          "grade": "AA",
          "gender": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "grade": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "b",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "c",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "aa",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Why the key become lowercase like 'aa' instead of 'AA'? How to get the key as its original value.

property setting like this:

```
       "grade": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
        "fielddata": true
      },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch aggregation turns results to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649217/elasticsearch-aggregation-turns-results-to-lowercase)

Comment: did you defined a mapping for the "key" field?

Comment: could you show definition of ik_max_word analyzer

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because you are using `lowercase filter` in your `ik_max_word` analyzer, Elastic search would use index data for aggregation purposes the best approach would be to remove `lowercase filter` or have another mapping for the field that are not Analyzed for aggregation purposes, for more information check  ES aggregation documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).